# Pagination icons for next set of results?

Tags: icons, pagination

Our search results page has pagination. We have links with the numbers one thru five to let the user navigate to the second, third, fourth, or fifth page of search results. After the number five, we want to offer users the chance to navigate to the next set of results (pages six thru ten). Currently our pagination looks like this:

1    2    3    4    5    >>   >>|

The double chevron is supposed to indicate that the user can jump to the next set of search results (pages six thru ten). We're not sure if the double chevron indicates that users are moving on to results 6-10 or if they think it is a "next" icon for the next page of results (e.g. to move to the second page of search results if you are currently on the first page).

Would it be better to add a single chevron in addition to the double chevron? Is it redundant to have the single chevron in addition to pages one thru five?

Comment: Something does not make sense here. Do you show a static `1 2 3 4 5 »` on result pages 1 through 5? And no relative ‘next page’ and ‘previous page’ links? Which results would you show if a user clicked to show pages 6 through 10? Auto-Pagination or Incremental Show All is usually a good thing, rendering this whole point moot. Elsewhere you should usually provide links to the first and last, next and previous one or two pages, maybe skip 5 or 10, too, or if results are sorted skip to adjacent keys. Anyway, most users only ever look at the first page of search results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be reasonably widely accepted that the outer buttons are the ones that 'go fastest', but it would definitely be confusing to have *two* double chevrons. One normally indicates one page and two... well... more than that!

The usual way to differentiate the next *one* vs the next *set* ( or first and last) is simply to use or include the word Next (or Previous) to clarify.

Some examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As a sidenote, I'd also highly recommend letting the user choose how many items to display on a page rather than doing the thinking for them.

---

ref: [Design Elements pagination gallery](http://www.smileycat.com/design_elements/pagination/index.php) and [Smashing Mag pagination gallery (2007!)](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/11/16/pagination-gallery-examples-and-good-practices/)